# OpenMP set_num_threads() is not working

Tags: c++, multithreading, numbers, set, openmp

I am writing a parallel program using OpenMP in C++.

I want to control the number of threads in the program using `omp_set_num_threads()`, but it does not work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <omp.h>
#include "mpi.h"

using namespace std;

int myrank;
int groupsize;
double sum;
double t1,t2;
int n = 10000000;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    MPI_Init( &argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank( MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myrank );
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&groupsize);

    omp_set_num_threads(4);

    sum = 0;
    #pragma omp for  reduction(+:sum)
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        sum+= i/(n/10);

    cout<<"sum="<<sum<<endl;
    cout<<"threads="<<omp_get_num_threads()<<endl;

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

The program outputs:

```
sum = 4.5e+007
threads=1
```

How to control the number of threads?

Answer (score 119, accepted):

Besides calling `omp_get_num_threads()` outside of the parallel region in your case, calling `omp_set_num_threads()` still doesn't guarantee that the OpenMP runtime will use exactly the specified number of threads. `omp_set_num_threads()` is used to override the value of the environment variable `OMP_NUM_THREADS` and they both control the *upper limit* of the size of the thread team that OpenMP would spawn for all parallel regions (in the case of `OMP_NUM_THREADS`) or for any consequent parallel region (after a call to `omp_set_num_threads()`). There is something called dynamic teams that could still pick smaller number of threads if the run-time system deems it more appropriate. You can disable dynamic teams by calling `omp_set_dynamic(0)` or by setting the environment variable `OMP_DYNAMIC` to `false`.

To enforce a given number of threads you should disable dynamic teams and specify the desired number of threads with either `omp_set_num_threads()`:

```
omp_set_dynamic(0);     // Explicitly disable dynamic teams
omp_set_num_threads(4); // Use 4 threads for all consecutive parallel regions
#pragma omp parallel ...
{
    ... 4 threads used here ...
}
```

or with the `num_threads` OpenMP clause:

```
omp_set_dynamic(0);     // Explicitly disable dynamic teams
// Spawn 4 threads for this parallel region only
#pragma omp parallel ... num_threads(4)
{
    ... 4 threads used here ...
}
```

Comment: But I couldn't get any acceleration by changing the number of threads and also by setting the omp_set_dynamic(0)??

Comment: First, the _serial_ version takes 50 ms on my CPU. You cannot expect speedup for such fast codes because of the OpenMP overhead. Put 100x more interations in the loop. Second, you are missing `parallel` region in your original code. You have written `#pragma omp for ...` while it should be `#pragma omp parallel for ...`. Third, you are mixing MPI and OpenMP. Are you sure you know exactly what you are doing?

Comment: @HristoIliev may a user dynamically control the number of threads? i.e. instead of using a hardcoded `4`. use a variable?

Comment: @manatttta, yes. The value gets passed to the OpenMP runtime library each time the parallel region is encountered during the execution of the program, therefore using a variable works as expected.

Comment: With the `num_threads` OpenMP clause option, is it possible to use a variable rather than hard code a number? E.g. `int n = 4; #pragma omp parallel ... num_threads(n)` ?

Comment: @OmarHaque, yes, the `num_threads` clause accepts variables too, so it is possible to control the number of threads in run time.

Answer (score 31):

The `omp_get_num_threads()` function returns the number of threads that are *currently in the team executing the parallel region from which it is called*. You are calling it outside of the parallel region, which is why it returns `1`.

Comment: I can confirm this. GNU implementation of omp documents this as well. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libgomp/omp_005fget_005fnum_005fthreads.html

Answer (score 9):

According to the [GCC manual for omp_get_num_threads](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libgomp/omp_005fget_005fnum_005fthreads.html):

> In a sequential section of the program omp_get_num_threads returns 1

So this:

```c++
cout<<"sum="<<sum<<endl;
cout<<"threads="<<omp_get_num_threads()<<endl;
```

Should be changed to something like:

```c++
#pragma omp parallel
{
    cout<<"sum="<<sum<<endl;
    cout<<"threads="<<omp_get_num_threads()<<endl;
}
```

The code I use follows Hristo's advice of disabling dynamic teams, too.

Answer (score 4):

I was facing the same problem . Solution is given below

Right click on Source Program > Properties > Configuration Properties > C/C++ > Language > Now change Open MP support flag to Yes....

You will get the desired result.