# Reading two different files simultaneously

Tags: c++, file, openmp

I have 2 files and i want each core read its own file ( each file has 5 lines ) and display its content 
in this code  I have 2 cores   ( core0 , core1)  the output core 0 read the content of core1  ( 5 lines ). and core1 read 4 lines from his content.

**I tried to make it as if else conditions and each file has its own reader  but the same problem still exist.what should i do ?**

```
    #include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


void func2(int CoreID )
{

    int iFace;
    int iFaces=0;
    if (CoreID==0)
    {
        FILE* imgListFile = 0;
        char imgFilename[5012];
        char actualPath[90]="C:\\DaliaDaliaSh\\TrainingFiles\\File10img_0_C";
        strcat(actualPath , "0.txt");
        imgListFile= freopen(actualPath , "r",stdin);
        while (fgets(imgFilename, 5012, imgListFile))
        {
            ++iFaces;
            printf( "** Core = %d , Path = %s\n" , CoreID , imgFilename );

        }
        rewind(imgListFile);
    }
    else if (CoreID==1)
    {
        FILE* imgListFile2 = 0;
        char imgFilename2[5012];
        char actualPath2[90]="C:\\DaliaDaliaSh\\TrainingFiles\\File10img_0_C";
        strcat(actualPath2 , "1.txt");
        imgListFile2= freopen(actualPath2 , "r",stdin);
        while (fgets(imgFilename2, 5012, imgListFile2))
        {
            ++iFaces;
            printf( "** Core = %d , Path = %s\n" , CoreID , imgFilename2 );

        }
        rewind(imgListFile2);
    }


    //printf ("*ID = %d open actualPath= %s\n" , myId , actualPath);


    printf("core %d , iFaces= %d \n", CoreID , iFaces);
}
void main(int argc,char **argv)
{ 
    MPI::Init(argc,argv);
    int threadnum=2;
    omp_set_num_threads(threadnum);

#pragma omp parallel 
    {

        int CoreID = omp_get_thread_num();
        int x ; 

        func2(CoreID);

        cout <<"@@@@after call func inside pragma \n" ;

    }


    MPI ::Finalize();
}
```

Comment: This could be useful, http://stackoverflow.com/a/11096742/5781248

Comment: Not sure I understood your question correctly, but I see a race condition while doing printf. This needs to be protected by a mutex/ std::unique_lock/ or some other scoped lock.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing `freopen` on `stdin`. Thus, both cores will use the same stream and the file read will depend upon which core opened the stream first/last [which is a race condition].

Do a regular `fopen` instead and they won't conflict [as they're doing now]